# Understanding Composition with Magento

Tags: dependency-injection

I am having a hard time trying to fully understand Composition with Magento. I am hoping you could help me with it.

From what I gather, we no longer should use inheritance, so my classes should not extend another and all of my code should be put in to classes that have a single purpose.

So is it right that I should do the following to implement a function?

```
• Create an interface
• Create a class and implement the interface
• Create a preference for that interface in the di.xml
• Pass the interface to another class, where it is to be used, using dependency injection
• Call the function on my interface
```

Thanks.

Comment: and what is your question? the list you created is correct

Answer (score 1):

Not really no. To implement a function you don't need all that. A simple class that has the function is enough.

What the "create an interface" and "create a preference for the interface" really provides is an API that ensures some functionality so it is easy for others to use, extend, or swap. The modularity Magento provides is its key strength.

You can read more in the documentation:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/api-concepts.html

Imagine that you have a private project and a module that has one class that does something very simple. Do you really need to have an interface, di.xml and the class itself? I think not.

At the same time, there are services that should follow this approach. You can read more about "Service contract" design here:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/design-patterns.html

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you.